# Is it possible to execute custom code in every Ajax request without having manually add that code to every ajax code in Ext Js?

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs

If user is logged in, then ajax requests work fine. When session is invalidated, ajax returns login screen and user can see login screens as ajax content. Is it possible to add custom code in Ext Js, that would be run every ajax request, to check if session is still valid, if session is not valid, then JavaScript would redirect to login page, otherwise it would continue execution Ajax request normally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ext.ajax is a singleton, so you can define a global handler for all request errors.

Your server side code will need to return a HTTP 403 or simmilar if the user is not authorised. Put this somewhere (only once) in your code code:

```
Ext.Ajax.on('requestexception', function(conn, response, options) {
    if (response.status == 403) {
       Ext.MessageBox.alert('Authentication', 'You are not logged in.');
       /* you can display a login box or something here */
    }
};
```

If an AJAX request fails because the session has expired, you can handle it gracefully in your code.

The options argument contains the AJAX request options, so if you present your user with a login box and reauthenticate them, you can resubmit the original AJAX request they were making automatically. The process should be seamless for all the rest of your existing code thats making AJAX requests.

Answer (score 1):

Checking whether the session is still valid *should* be done in the server. Not in JavaScript.

We do not trust clients.

Comment: It is done on server side, but Ext Js is like JavaScript OS, so it would be easier to check if session is valid automatically in every ajax request, instead of writing same code for that every ajax request.

Comment: @newbie why check on the client? Just add some middleware to your ajax handler on the server to check the session and return the log in screen if it goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You could modify your ajax process in two ways:

1- server end: on receiving a request, check session - if user not logged in or session expired, return an HHTP 403 (=not authorised).
2- client end: as part of your ajax response handler, check for error 403. If it is returned, ask for login and send that to server, then when login has been successful, resend orginal request.

That's easy if you're not using too many ready-made ajax libraries. If you are, look to its functionality.